# Note: binaryTree.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations error when using compareTo() method

Tags: java

I'm writing the following method and receiving the error in the post tile when trying to compile. The compareTo method is causing it and I can't find out why. Is there a different method I should be using to compare my keys?

```
    public java.lang.Object insert(java.lang.Comparable key, java.lang.Object value){
        TreeNode insertable = new TreeNode();
        insertable.key = key;
        insertable.value = value;
        
        if (this.getRoot() == null){
            root = insertable;
            return value;
        }

        TreeNode cur = this.getRoot();
        while(cur != null){
            if(key.compareTo(cur.key) == 0){
                java.lang.Object oldVal = cur.value;
                cur.value = value;
                return oldVal;
            }
            if(key.compareTo(cur.key) == 1){
                cur = cur.right;
            }
            if(key.compareTo(cur.key) == -1){
                cur = cur.left;
            }
        }
        cur = insertable;
        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Yes. You should be using generic types. This code is very fragile. `key` and `value` are not related.

Comment: The `Comparable` class is a **generic** type.  You should read about generics so that you know how to use them.  If you don't have a set textbook or lecture notes covering this, start with the [Oracle Java > Generics Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).